# Incremental Area Under the Curve (iAUC) in R

Tags: r

The area under the curve can be calculated using the *trapz* function of the *pracma* package in R. iAUC is much more accurate in many instances, particularly in biology. However there is no, to me known, R function to calculate this. The trap function follows:

Example:

```
a <- c(1, 4, 5, 6)
b <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
plot(a, b)
trapz(a, b)
```

Answer: 21

Does anyone know how to use R to calculate the iAUC? A guide can be found [here](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjADahUKEwjzoIvEi6LHAhVI_nIKHSO1CgQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.bath.ac.uk%2Fjb335%2FY2%2520Research%2520Skills%2520(FH200107)_files%2FCalculation%2520of%2520Incremental%2520Area%2520Under%2520Curve.doc&ei=t3jKVbPpMcj8ywOj6qog&usg=AFQjCNHWIkrXKoQaGO6VNpjyLLim2HDfWA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGQ).

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
**In response to Cheng-Yow's answer below:**
Another example

```
# Recall that trapz-function is available in the pracma package
# Here is the function kindly provided by Cheng-Yow Timothy Lin
library(pracma) # should be loaded already
traps <- function(a, b) {
     for (i in 1:length(b)-1){
          iAUC[i] <-((b[i]+b[i+1])/2)*(a[i+1]-a[i])
     }
     return(sum(iAUC))
}

# Data example
a <- c(-15,  -5,   1,   2,   3,   5,   8,  10,  15,  20,  30,  45,  60,  90, 120)
b <- c(50.20604,  49.59338,  47.39944,  56.38831,  69.43493,  73.92512,  61.92072,  67.92632, 115.45669,
195.03242, 322.15894, 291.30094, 289.20284, 238.70562, 156.23798)

traps(a, b)

trapz(a, b)
```

They yield the same results- is this the incremental area under the curve? It is not how they have explained the trapz-function...

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,-1,-2,2)
plot(a,b)
lines(a, b)
abline(b[1],0)
iAUC <- vector()

for (i in 1:(length(a)-1)){

  if((b[i+1]-b[1] >= 0) && (b[i]-b[1] >= 0))
  {iAUC[i] <-((b[i]-b[1]+b[i+1]-b[1])/2)*(a[i+1]-a[i])} 

  else if((b[i+1]-b[1] < 0) && (b[i]-b[1] >= 0))
  {iAUC[i] <-(b[i]-b[1])*((b[i]-b[1])/(b[i]-b[i+1])*(a[i+1]-a[i])/2)} 

  else if((b[i+1]-b[1] >= 0) && (b[i]-b[1] < 0))
  {iAUC[i] <-(b[i+1]-b[1])*((b[i+1]-b[1])/(b[i+1]-b[i])*(a[i+1]-a[i])/2)} 

  else if((b[i]-b[1] < 0) && (b[i+1]-b[1] < 0))
  {iAUC[i] <- 0}
}
sum(iAUC)
iAUC
```

Comment: Many many thanks Cheng-Yow for a nice function. Please see my update in the question above, as a response to your function.

Comment: Hi Adam, one of the key differences is that my code uses a loop, which is slow when your data gets larger. The function in the pracma package is vectorized so it will perform much faster. Try running this after your snippet above! 
`a <- rep(a,1000)
b <- rep(b,1000)
plot(a,b)
ptm <- proc.time()
traps(a, b)
proc.time()-ptm

ptm <- proc.time()
trapz(a, b)
proc.time()-ptm`Also, don't forget to initalze iAUC vector with `iAUC<-vector()` in your function 'traps'"

Comment: Many thanks @Cheng-Yow, but does your traps function provide the incremental AUC (I'm sorry for repeating a possibly stupid question)?

Comment: Because it provides the same answer as pracma, which does not state that it calculates incremental AUC... =)

Comment: I just reread your word document that you provided. Sorry, according to Woelver, the pracma and the function i wrote does not calculate iAUC. it just calculates AUC. iAUC is baseline corrected, which means that instead of taking the areas about the origin, y=0, it takes y=(baseline measure, or first measure) I will edit my answer to reflect these changes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: many many thanks for the answers You have provided, I really appreciate Your time. However, copying and pasting the code directly into R, trying to execute it, failed. I tried editing it (although that's beyond me) but couldn't figure it out. Did anyone else have troubles executing it? Moreover, the reason for the: "for (i in 1:4){" is it because there are four change-points? It would be lovely if the code was general, so that it could be used for data sets with varying number of x's and y's. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Applying the code to the vector I provided (a and b from the original post) returns an implausible value. I apologize if I've misunderstood the code.

Comment: I did a quick check, appears to be correct now! A million thanks!